# Set value using select

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am new to using postgresql, I am trying to make a trigger that just inserts in the Employee table and also inserts in the Vacations table, but I don't know how to assign the values, I do it like that in sql but here I really don't know how

```
    CREATE FUNCTION SP_InsertaVacacionesEmpleado() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS

$$
DECLARE _NumeroIdentificacion INTEGER;
DECLARE _FechaEntrada DATE;

    BEGIN
        
        SET _NumeroIdentificacion = SELECT NEW.NumeroIdentificacion FROM "Empleado"
        SET _FechaEntrada = SELECT NEW.FechaEntrada FROM "Empleado"
        INSERT INTO Vacaciones VALUES(_NumeroIdentificacion, _FechaEntrada, '', 0);
        RETURN NEW;
    END

$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) assignment is done using the `:=` operator, e.g.:

```
some_variable := 42;
```

However to assign one or more variables from the result of a query, use [select into](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW), e.g.:

```
DECLARE 
  var_1 INTEGER;
  var_2 DATE;
BEGIN
   select col1, col2
      into var_1, var_2
   from some_table
...
```

However neither of that is necessary in a trigger as you can simply use the reference to the NEW record directly in the INSERT statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sp_insertavacacionesempleado() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Vacaciones (...)
  VALUES (NEW.NumeroIdentificacion, NEW.FechaEntrada , '', 0);
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note that you need to define a row level trigger for this to work:

```
create trigger ..
  before insert on ...
  for each row --<< important!
  execute procedure sp_insertavacacionesempleado() ;
```